# How do I Extract mean from a summary() table in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, mean, summary

I've successfully created a table and summary of the data, but how can I extract the means from the table? (mean(VeryActiveminutes), mean(FairlyActiveMinutes), etc.). Is there something I can add to the summary function?

```
totalTime <- Activity %>% 
  select(VeryActiveMinutes, FairlyActiveMinutes, LightlyActiveMinutes, SedentaryMinutes) %>% 
  summary()
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuaiA.png)

I've tried using mean(), but unable to inside a table. I've also tried summing the values of each dataset,

```
AvgVeryActiveMinutes=sum(VeryActiveMinutes$VeryActiveMinutes)/nrow(VeryActiveMinutes)
```

but that seems quite repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

`summary` here does a lot of things, it's actually a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155609/6574038) and dispatches to `summary.data.frame` in this case.

If you want the `mean` of specific columns of a data frame, you can use `mean` in an `lapply`. Here demonstrated on the `mtcars` dataset that comes with R:

```
lapply(X=mtcars[c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')], FUN=mean)
# $mpg
# [1] 20.09062
# 
# $cyl
# [1] 6.1875
# 
# $disp
# [1] 230.7219
```

Answer (score 0):

`mean` expects a vector as input. For vectorized mean operations, select the columns and use `colMeans` from `base R`

```
nm1 <- c("VeryActiveMinutes", "FairlyActiveMinutes",
  "LightlyActiveMinutes", "SedentaryMinutes")
colMeans(Activity[nm1],  na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

For the `tidyverse`, `mean` can be applied within `across`

```
library(dplyr)
Activity %>%
   summarise(across(all_of(nm1), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```